# Do any of the Developers Update the Answers when new capabilities are added to Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

Does anyone think to Update the more frequently asked questions when new versions of Ubuntu are released with new capabilities that may Change to "Best" answer to the questions?

This process would need someone with an in depth knowledge of the newest releases to review the questions and update any answers that might have Changed because of better tools now available.

I wondered about this when I began to notice that a lot of the questions have answers that are 3 or more years old.

Comment: This is more of a [meta] question.  Flagged for migration to meta.

Comment: "developers"? Why are they needed to update answers from users?

Comment: @Rinzwind they might volunteer. I think some of Colin Watson's answers here came about this way. And of course, anything that connects nginx and ThomasW.

Comment: I would assume if someone is registered on AU he/she is a user. If the person is a developer of something fine but ...to me he/she would still just be a user. Those 2 are exceptions. They need to find a hobby. Oh wait. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Please keep in mind, that even though this site is officially certified by canonical, this is still a [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) site. Meaning that most people answering here are not actual canonical employees nor developers. They are volunteers just like you and I.

Keeping that in mind, the issue with outdated and obsolete answers governs most of the Stack Exchange sites, to a point that a Q&A was created on the [main meta site of Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

You can check the status of that question in the following link, and you can even participate as well: [How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261817/how-do-we-encourage-edits-to-obsolete-out-of-date-answers)